# What is a "370 XA sysV" executable?

Tags: linux, files

I have a file called logcache.v2 and logcache.v2-journal. I run the `file` command on the former (the latter is empty) and I get this:

```
 370 XA sysV executable not stripped
```

What is this file and how can I further analyze it?

Thank

Comment: I would presume an executable intended to run on machines based on the IBM "System 5" 370 Extended Architecture. Which mostly means large commercial mainframes.

Comment: That sounds like a misidentification; the `file` command is not magic. It just looks for certain bytes to be at different offsets.

Comment: That matches on files that are at least 16 byte long, whose first 2 bytes are 0x1 and 0x5f and at least one of the 12th to 16th bytes is not NUL.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official homepage of the [file command](https://darwinsys.com/file/):

> The file command is "a file type guesser"

It uses heuristics (as some antivirus does) encoded in magic files to guess useful information about a file.

The `370 XA sysV executable` string refers to a [IBM System/370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/370) type of computer running some kind of [System V Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V).

You can look at the magic file of the ibm370 [here](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/ibm370).

What happens in your case, most probably, and according to the file names `logcache.v2` and `logcache.v2-journal` is that the file command guess incorrectly.

Comment: The comment on the *magic* file says that the developer didn't actually know what *USS* is.  That's [Unix System Services](https://www.zmainframes.com/viewtopic.php?t=49).  Whether sysV is appropriate is debatable.